# Cortex M3 in privileged mode

Tags: arm, cortex-m

I want ot make output debug information via SWO (use ITM). Core Cortex M3 can do it.

> The ITM is a an application driven trace source that supports printf style debugging to trace 
>   Operating System (OS) and application events, and emits diagnostic system information...
>   [link](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0337e/BABCCDFD.html)

For this I have to configure ITM registers.Part of them I can write only in privileged mode.

> ITM Trace Privilege Register
>   Use the ITM Trace Privilege Register to enable an operating system to control which stimulus ports are accessible by user code.
>   Note:
>   You can only write to this register in privileged mode. [see ITM Trace Privilege Register](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0337e/BABCCDFD.html)

What is the best way to switch in privileged mode if IRQs SVC, PendSV, SysTick has already used? (I use FreeRTOS) Is it real?

Comment: Since you presumably only need to write to this register once, can't you just do that in the OS startup code, rather than trying to mode-switch later?

Comment: Of course I can do it. But I want to initialize ITM registers in my dbg_init() function.

Answer (score 0):

Either you configure ITM before starting FreeRTOS (considering the FreeRTOS tasks run in non-privilege mode).
Or you add support for a new SVC. FreeRTOS SVC uses `svc 0`, you could add support for a new `svc`, let's call it `svc 1` and your `SVC_Handler()` will either redirect `svc 0` to FreeRTOS or `svc 1` to your ITM configuration code.